# Sharing styles between modules in Silverlight applications based on Prism 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism-4

I need to use the styles in several modules in Silverlight application based on Prism 4.
What is the best approach for this?

Comment: Having same problem, because all modules are separate applications they should refernce common libiriaries to be able to build. This will enlarge the final size of application by O(N) of modules.

Comment: Yes yes but no... The main reason is to make posibility see changes in VS designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding the resources to your prism shell project and adding a reference to the shell module project in all the other modules.

Comment: To avoid cyclic references, use a common project as well (referenced by all the modules) to hold shared controls, classes etc.